# How can I replace the type = date Valuse using my "SearchDate" in python template,

Tags: javascript, python, html

I got search_date from my view, so I want to display this data in a template, How I can do? object.date = "2020-09-01"

I write down like code but don't work

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    <td>date : {{ object.date|date:"j-m-Y" }}</td>  
             <-- this can display date:2020-09-01>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
       <label>Date</label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="workdate" id="PickingDate"                              
         value="{{ object.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}"> 
        <!-- input area display YYYY-MM-DD, I want to display the 2020-09-01 -->
                </div>
    {% endblock %} 
       
    
    <script>
```

Comment: What date format did you pass in? Is it YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: yes， the date format can be yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Your code looks fine, check if the search_date is passed properly from your view. Even if the search_date is not passed, it looks like your $('#PickingDate').val(today); should assign the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand where you want to show the date value.

---

let's assume: you want to show inside any HTML- template.

use `{{ search_date }}`

---

if you want to assign the date value to some javascript variable :
and then using `document.getElementById("PickingDate").value = {{ search_date }}`  you can also provide the value to input field.

```
<script>
     var datevalue = {{ search_date }}
     document.getElementById("PickingDate").value = datevalue
</script>
```

---

as per  Neo Yumnam (on the comment): if you just want to assign the attribute 'value' to today's date so that the date picker shows today's date :

just make the **search_date** variable in python of the format "YYYY-MM-DD". then HTML will automatically pick the date you passed.

Comment: innerHTML is for inserting value inside a tag, I think he wants to assign the attribute 'value' to today's date so that the datepicker shows today's date

Comment: ok, now I understand the question.  just change the value of  {{search_date}} to propper date format by python , so that js can parse it

Comment: <input type="date"  value="{{search_date}}">. This is enough . And remove the javascript part . It will change the date value again